# Why is there an array at the end of this function using reduce?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am working on an exercise involving the reduce array method. After the accumulator is returned what is the reason for adding the `, []`? Is it just an empty array? My tests did not pass without it until after viewing the answer and adding it to my function. Thanks!

```js
function extractValue(arr, key) {
    return arr.reduce((accum, nextName) => {
        accum.push(nextName[key]);
        return accum;
    }, []);
}
// const arr = [{name: 'Elie'}, {name: 'Tim'}, {name: 'Matt'}, {name: 'Colt'}]
// extractValue(arr,'name') // ['Elie', 'Tim', 'Matt', 'Colt']
```

Comment: Its the default initialization value of the accumulator, in which things get accumulated

Comment: If you want to know what the second argument of a function does, how about [reading the documentation for it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)?

Comment: This code really should have used the `map` method instead of `reduce`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read the official documentation for the .reduce method
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

That empty array is the initialValue parameter.